# Equivalente de funcion SUM(SQL) en MongoDB (NodeJS y Mongoose)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo los siguientes esquemas hechos con mongoose:

```
const soldProductsSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Id - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Name - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    },
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Brand - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Quantity - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    },
    unitPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'UnitPrice - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    },
    subtotal: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Subtotal - soldProductsSchema es obligatorio']
    }
})

const saleSchema = new Schema({
    nroFact: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'NroFact es obligatorio']
    },
    total:{
        type: Number,
        required:[true, 'Total es obligatorio'] 
    },
    soldProducts:{
        type: [soldProductsSchema], // <---- Array de productos
        required: [true, 'Soldproducts es obligatorio']
    }
})
```

En el que básicamente quiero registrar una venta y almacenar una lista de productos correspondientes a la misma en forma de array. Mongodb me da la facilidad de almacenar un array de objetos en un campo, a diferencia de las bases de datos relacionales en las que claramente romperiamos la 1ra. forma normal.

Pero vengo de SQl y en el caso de que quiera obtener un listado de productos ordenados según la cantidad de unidades vendidas haría lo siguiente (teniendo en cuenta que se trata de dos tablas distintas):

```
SELECT name, sum(quantity) 
FROM soldProducts
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sum(quantity) ASC
```

Teniendo en cuenta mis esquemas, quisiera poder obtener el mismo resultado, sabiendo que los productos y sus cantidades vendidas se encuentran en ventas separadas.

Leí la documentación de mongo, y el ejemplo de $sum() tiene un ejemplo con documentos, y no se como aplicarlo a las propiedades de los documentos que contienen array de productos.

Espero se haya entendido la duda.

Incluso dudo si mi modelado es el correcto para que me permita obtener el resultado que necesito. Estoy presto a escuchar sus sugerencias.

Mil gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes de realizarlo con `Aggregation operations`, que procesan múltiples documentos y devuelven resultados calculados.

‎Para realizarlo puede utilizar `Aggregation pipelines` que consta de una o más ‎‎etapas‎‎ que procesan documentos. ‎Cada etapa realiza una operación en los documentos de entrada. ‎Los documentos que se generan de una etapa se pasan a la siguiente etapa.‎

```
// TU CONSULTA SQL
SELECT 
  name, 
  sum(quantity) 
FROM soldProducts
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY sum(quantity) ASC    

// EN MONGODB QUEDARIA...
db.soldProducts.aggregate( [ 
 { $group: { _id: "$name", totalQuantity: { $sum: "$quantity" } } }, 
 { $sort: { totalQuantity: 1 } } 
] )
```

En `.aggregate()` debes enviar una lista con las diferentes etapas que necesites. Primero agrupa los documentos por nombre de pizza y calcule la cantidad total asignándolo a totalQuantity, y por último, se ordena por totalQuantity (1 para ordenar ascendentemente y -1 para la forma descendente).

Revisa este enlace [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Esta solución me devuelve el nombre y la suma de las cantidades, como podría modificarlo para que me aparezca también el id del producto?

Comment: Agregando, como puedo filtrar esta información según, una fecha?, por ejemplo

Comment: Para lograr eso debes modificar el modelo de tu DB, si te das cuenta en tu modelo de productos vendidos sólo guardas los nombres de los productos no los Ids, tampoco guardas ninguna fecha. Si tuvieras un campo date, podrías agregar al inicio la etapa: { $match: { date: { $gte: new Date("2022-01-01"), $lte: new Date("2022-12-31") } } } para filtrar por rango de fechas.

Comment: Perdón, me olvide de mencionar que si, aumente el productId

Comment: Para darte una solución rápida, podrías agregar en tu primera etapa:  { $group: { idProduct: {$push: 'idProduct' }, ... } que te va a devolver un array con los valores de los campos idProduct encontrados, que vendrían siendo el mismo valor repetido.